# Swift 3 mutating functions missing ('...inPlace' methods)

Tags: swift, swift3

In Swift 2.3, we can write something like this:

```
var rect = CGRect(...)
rect.offsetInPlace(dx: 15, dy: 0)
```

to move a rect 15pt to the right.

However in Swift 3, it seems like this function does no longer exist.
When inspecting the `CGRect` interface we can only see the non mutating variant `offsetBy(dx:, dy:)`. This is also true in all the places we've usually used mutating functions (named `...inPlace`). I have already searched the Swift evolution repo on GitHub, but couldn't find any notes about this.

Have the mutating variants been removed? Is the remaining function automatically mutating depending on whether or not the return value is used? IMHO, it would be a shame, if they have actually been removed, because they used to be very convenient when doing code based layout, etc.

Comment: It doesn't show as deprecated https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgrect/1455748-offsetinplace

Comment: in the meantime you can do as follow `extension CGRect {
    mutating func offsetInPlace(dx: CGFloat, dy: CGFloat) {
        self = offsetBy(dx: dx, dy: dy)
    }
}`

Comment: Yes I know I could go ahead and write extensions for things that are missing. But I'd rather avoid doing so for ALL the ..inPlace methods usually provided by the framework itself..

Comment: I just provided you a way of keeping your code as it was before. You can refactor your code if you want. https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgrect offsetInPlace is not listed there anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there is no `offsetInPlace` anymore. Please see the screen here is all available functions in `Instance Methods`
[image]

Comment: Did they remove this via oversight, or are there a load of mutating functions that are no longer existing? (I just converted my app to 3.0 and I used offsetInPlace a lot)

Comment: @solenoid Hi made more research about this and seems this function load to mutating. Please review this link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/iOS91APIDiffs/Swift/CoreGraphics.html

Answer (score 14):

You can make one for compatibility.

```
extension CGRect {
    mutating func offsetInPlace(dx: CGFloat, dy: CGFloat) {
        self = self.offsetBy(dx: dx, dy: dy)
    }
}
```